# Formatting a logical (PD) derivation

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm trying to format a PD derivation but I'm having trouble getting subderivations to display well.  Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
1 | P          Assumption
2 | Q          Assumption
  ------------
3 | P v Q      1, 2 vI
4 | | P        A / vE
  | --------
5 | | R
6 | R
```

The above is all nonsense but it shows the format I need.  Basically, I need one column for line numbers followed by a vertical line, a horizontal line under assumptions ("A" also means assumption) and a third column explaining the derivation rule I used with the corresponding line numbers.  Without the subderivation I can do it with tables like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{l | l l}
  1 & P & Assumption \\
  2 & Q & Assumption \\ [0.5ex] \cline{2-2} \\ [-1.9ex]
  3 & P v Q & 1, 2 vI \\
\end{tabular}
```

For a little more detail, the vertical bars and their associated horizontal bar should be connected and the vertical bars for the subderivations should be spaced so they're pretty close to being underneath the first character of the line above it.  I thought about making a new table inside the whole table for each subderivation, but I feel like that would mess up the line numbering since it would only occupy a single cell.  Any suggestions as to how I should lay this out are greatly appreciated.

Here's an image of the desired layout (added by Gonzalo Medina, from an image linked in a comment):

[image]

Comment: Could you draw a picture?  I'm not quite getting your ASCII art in light of your last paragraph.

Comment: Here's an image of a derivation my professor did: http://imgur.com/O9ZZ94e  Gonzalo Medina's answer below is very close to what I need, though I'd prefer if the horizontal lines extended further like in this image (if only because that's how my professor has been doing it).

Comment: @user29553 please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site [`LaTeX for logicians`](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) mentions various packages availables; the following example was obtained using [`fitch.sty`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120313232308/http://folk.uio.no/johanw/FitchSty.html) by Johan Klüwer (the package is not on CTAN, but following the link I provided you can download it). To get the desired horizontal rule I defined a `\fgh` command similar to the original `\fh` command; the mandatory argument for `\fgh` gives the rule length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fitch}

\newcommand{\fgh}[1]{\fvline%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{{%
      \raisebox{-1.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{#1}{\arrayrulewidth}}}}%
  \hspace*{\fitchindent}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{fitch}
    \fgh{14.5em} \forall y\lnot P(y)    & Assumption \\
    \fa\fh \exists xP(x)        &  \\
    \fa\fa\fitchmodalh{u}  P(u) & \\
    \fa\fa\fa \forall y\lnot P(y) & R, 1                \\
    \fa\fa\fa \lnot P(u)          & $\forall$E, 4       \\
    \fa\fa\fa \bot                & $\lnot$E, 3,5       \\
    \fa\fa \bot                   & $\exists$E, 2, 3--6 \\
    \fa \lnot\exists xP(x)        & $\lnot$I, 2--7
  \end{fitch}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An here's the code for the deduction in the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fitch}

\newcommand\Impl{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{$\cap$}}}
\newcommand{\fgh}[1]{\fvline%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{{%
      \raisebox{-1.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{#1}{\arrayrulewidth}}}}%
  \hspace*{\fitchindent}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{fitch}
    \fa\forall x (Fx \vee Rx)    & Assumption \\
    \fa\forall x (Fx \Impl Wx)    & Assumption \\
    \fgh{22em} \forall x (Rx \Impl Px) \land \forall x (Px \Impl Wx) & Assumption  \\
    \fa Fa \vee Ra & 1,$\forall$E \\
    \fa\fgh{8em} Fa & A / $\vee$E \\
    \fa\fa Fa \Impl Wa & 2 $\forall$E \\
    \fa\fa Wa & 5,6 $\Impl\,$E \\
    \fa\fgh{8em} Ra & A / $\vee$E \\
    \fa\fa \forall x (Rx \Impl Px) & 3 $\land$E \\
    \fa\fa Ra \Impl Pa & 9 $\forall$E \\
    \fa\fa Pa & 8,10 $\Impl\,$E \\
    \fa\fa \forall x (Px \Impl Wx) & 3 $\land$E \\
    \fa\fa Pa \Impl Wa & 12 $\forall$E \\
    \fa\fa Wa & 11,13 $\Impl\,$E \\
    \fa Wa & 4,5--7,8--14 $\vee$E \\
    \fa\forall x Wx & 15, $\forall$I
  \end{fitch}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user29553 You're welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure it would be better in this case but note that `lplfitch` is included in standard distributions, such as TeX Live. I think it may be newer but I'm not sure how you'd get the horizontal lines at the correct length in that case. (Maybe the solution here could be adapted.) Note that the outer scope line should really not be broken like that as it technically changes the meaning in a way which would render the derivation invalid. (Obviously people would realise what is meant and that it is just a typesetting error but it would be better avoided if possible.)